# SortedDictionary in c

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to use the following code (written in C#) in C++

```
SortedDictionary<object[], int> test = 
                                    new SortedDictionary<object[], int>(new Comparer());
```

Is it possible to use SortedDictionary in C++, or are there any alternatives that will allow me to have more or less the same functionality without making too much change to the rest of my codebase?

Comment: it would definitely be uglier...;)

Comment: Do you **really** want to use `SortedDictionary` from your C++ code, or are you just looking for an equivalent?

Comment: @g-makulik It would actually be better if I could use SortedDictionary, but if that's not possible, an alternative that doesn't require me to change much in the rest of the code base would be fine as well.

Comment: Then `std::map` is the right way to go. You can also use `SortedDictionary` for C++ CLI, but I'd suspect it being easier to handle in C++. For interfacing C# code it might be better though.

Comment: @g-makulik  
Would it be possible to pass System.object[] as the key?

Comment: I have the feeling you're looking for the C++ CLI equivalent. Just go to your Documentation (`SortedDictionary`) and select 'C++' as language.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to get familiar with STL! I think [STL map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) would do?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `std::map`.

Comment: Would it be possible to pass System.object[] as the key?

Comment: Yes, but it wouldn't serve for interfacing C# code well. Look at my comment.

Comment: System.Object is C#/C++CLI. In plain C++ you the equivalent would be a vector of some objects - weird choice but possible as long as you provide custom comparator.

Answer (score 0):

As reading from your comments it looks you want to use [`System::Collections::Generic::SortedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) from C++ CLI. You can more or less use it the same was as you're doing in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).